# How to replace href of all anchor tags in a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make a bookmarklet that changes every link on a page to "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" and iv'e gotten this far:

```
a.forEach(function(a){
a.href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";
});
alert("done.");
```

The html editor shows that the href of the "a" tag has changed but won't go to the new link. Im using this bookmarklet on websites I don't own, so I can't add classes or id's.

If you are going to close the question due to it being a duplicate, please tell me the duplicate.

Comment: If the `href` gets updated, then clicking that link will go to that URL. There's really not much that can break there: either the `href` got updated, and the link now points to that new location, or the `href` did _not_ get updated, and the link still goes to the original location, so: can you [edit] the code in your post that shows what the `a` array is, and can you add an explanation of how you're testing this.

Comment: You want to change every link on a web-page that you're viewing, that won't affect anyone other than you, to link to the same destination URL? It's certainly possible, but I can't imagine why you want to do this; have you simplified your real problem too much?

Comment: you inner variable has the same name as the outer, that may be the issue.

Comment: @Gavin: not really, it'll just shadow the array, but we don't need access to the array inside the forEach

Comment: If the links load dynamically (after the initial page load), or after your script runs, you will have to run it again, or use a `MutationObserver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`javascript:var url="https://github.com/"; var all_links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");for (var link_num = 0; link_num < all_links.length; link_num++) {var link = all_links[link_num];link.href = url;};alert("changed " + link_num + " links")`

Change the `url` variable to whatever you want and it should change all links to that and alert the amount of links changed.

Comment: It doesn't work for khan academy but everything else. Do you know why?

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do might be more easily done via the Tampermonkey browser extension.

Your code might look like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Change all A Tags
// @namespace    MyNameSpaceItsMe
// @match        https://yourdomain.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

'use strict';
const allA = document.querySelectorAll('a');

allA.forEach( (a) => {
    a.setAttribute("href", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");
});
```

Here is some information about Tampermonkey:

[What is Tampermonkey and what can it do for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53161629)

[Some tips for getting started with Tampermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77881188)

[Where to find Tampermonkey in the Chrome Web Store](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)

[Video tutorial for getting started with Tampermonkey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnCvr2TMIv0)

[Another short video re getting started with Tampermonkey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiq0wOJQyaY)