# How to click on specific elements on a webpage and find the last page of searches then find specific class to save in txt file

Tags: javascript

First of all, I don't know what to search in Google for this question, and I don't know JavaScript.

I googled keywords like this: `javascript console search one class or tag`, `javascript console fetch tag in console` and things like this.

I'm a member of a website and they don't have any APIs yet for this issue. I asked them and they said that's in their roadmap and they'll add it.

**Scenario**

1. I login to the website `site.com/login` as a human with normal behavior.
2. I go to `site.com/myServices`, then I click on the `100` string to show 100 services per page and my URL changes to `site.com/myServices?t_count=100`
3. In the first page I have 100 services with this tag: `<a href="viewServices?service=serviceA.com"><span dir="ltr" class="text_render">serviceA.com</span></a>`
4. The next page URL is `site.com/myServices?t_page=2`. Also the first page can be accessed via `site.com/myServices?t_page=1`.
5. Then and finally, I'm going to save all of the texts inside the above `<a href='...'><span dir='ltr' class='text_render'>...</span></a>` into something like a `txt` file with each service name in a separated line.

I'm seeing the current real-world HTML regarding how to find the pages by HTML, but these are the ways:

1. It says: `1 از 60` (we see the text incorrect due to LTR/RLT issues). In English it means `1 of 60` which means `page 1 of 60 pages`. I see it's HTML is like this: `<b>1</b> از <b>60</b>`. In this case, the number `60` (in regex I think it should be like this `[0-9]{1,3}` to find the last page.

How can I do this in JavaScript in my laptop as a normal human behavior? I mean instead of opening all pages at the same time and inspect element for all of them, I use JavaScript for this case.

I also should be mentioned that the website shows 504 if I open many pages in a short period of time. I'm not sure but I think I can open 5 URLs each minute (I once did this process by my mouse and clicks and I'm not sure if that's correct or not, but they have a rate limit for this).

Do you please help me for this case:

1. What can I do?
2. What can I search?
3. What topics are related to? I know it may be many topics like A, B, C, etc. And I'd like to know which topics I should read, so I can learn and use them one by one, and if I had any issues then I'll know the words to search, and I also will know what to ask specifically.

Comment: You're much better off doing this in Python. Try out beautifulsoup. There are examples everywhere online, and it'll be much easier to get running for someone who hasn't been working with web scraping too much before.

Comment: @LukePoirrier thanks, I know python a little, but I thought it may be easier or faster in JavaScript.

Comment: Well if you're more familiar with JavaScript and would rather use that you can, but you should use Node.js to do it because there are already packages that handle what you want to do. I do believe it would be harder though if you've never used Node.js before though. Either way, Good Luck!

Comment: @LukePoirrier no I've never worked with Node.JS. So I think I should prefer to pythonic ways.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a textbook example of what the browser extension Tampermonkey was invented for.

Tampermonkey allows you to do any/all of the following:

1. Search the web page (DOM) for specific words / elements
2. Grab information and store in a variable or [in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537112/when-is-localstorage-cleared/37105645#37105645)
3. Click buttons, enter text into controls
4. Navigate from page to page

And much more.

It does all this by allowing you to inject javascript and CSS/HTML onto any web page. No need to learn Python.

With Tampermonkey, you do not need to write an extension ("add-on"). Tampermonkey is the browser extension, and you add it like any other browser add-on. [Here is the link](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for the Tampermonkey extension for Chrome. (*Tampermonkey is not just for Google Chrome - you can get a Tampermonkey extension for all popular browsers, via their usual extension/add-on pages*).

With Tampermonkey, you can create little bits of javascript and CSS that Tampermonkey will inject onto the page just before it displays that page to you. You can completely reformat the page - you can even add new things onto the page that were not there originally (buttons, images, pop-ups...)

There are also many pre-written Tampermonkey scripts that you can install into your instance of Tampermonkey. [Here is one example](https://github.com/cssyphus/TamperMonkeyUserscripts?tab=readme-ov-file#tampermonkeyuserscripts) of a repository of a few Tampermonkey scripts.

[Here is an article](https://simply-how.com/enhance-and-fine-tune-any-web-page-the-complete-user-scripts-guide) that will get you started using Tampermonkey.

Some additional information about Tampermonkey:

[What is Tampermonkey and what can it do for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53161629)

[Some tips for getting started with Tampermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77881188)

[Where to find Tampermonkey in the Chrome Web Store](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)

[Video tutorial for getting started with Tampermonkey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnCvr2TMIv0)

[Another short video re getting started with Tampermonkey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiq0wOJQyaY)

#### Some important info that applies to your use case:

1. You can pretty much easily navigate from page-to-page on the same domain.  Just parse `document.URL` to determine what page you are on.  You can access the same localStorage variable as long as you are on the same domain.